# php strlen function not working in an if statement

Tags: php

I am using the following code in a function:

```
if ( strlen( $year > 4 )) { 
    return "Position year must be a 4 digit year  - The ".$year. " length is ".strlen($year);
}
```

I pass in a string "2014" which should evaluate to false.  For some reason the if statement evaluates to true and executes the return.  The returned string actually prints out the year 2014 and a length of 4 for the value of strlen($year).  Why is this not working properly?

Comment: Should be `if ( strlen( $year) > 4 ) { ...`

Comment: because it evaluates `$year > 4` first, then the function `strlen` is applied, logic is apply the function first `strlen($year)`, then apply the condition `if ( strlen($year) > 4 )`

Comment: Other guys already answered. The problem is about order of brackets. I strongly recommend you one very small trick which can save your time many times. Whenever you open a bracket ([({) immediately close it. Then go back and fill the content. ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( strlen( $year) > 4 ) { 
    return "Position year must be a 4 digit year  - The ".$year. " length is ".strlen($year);
}
```

You have the round bracket in wrong place.
You can learn more about this function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Answer (score 0):

Wrongly placed the condition

```
if ( strlen( $year ) > 4 ) { 
    return "Position year must be a 4 digit year  - The ".$year. " length is ".strlen($year);
}
```

[strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) will return the length of the function, and comparing with length is what you needed `strlen( $year ) > 4` so it will return true when $year string length is greater than 4 else false.

Answer (score 0):

As you could see, the usage of `strlen` of yours is wrong, it should be `strlen($year) > 4` instead of `strlen( $year > 4 )`.
The latter parameter will see the value of `$year > 4` as the parameter of `strlen`, as a result, it returns a `bool(true)`, which leads to return the string.